# Find occurrences of alphabets in a command line argument

Tags: c++

I'm new here!
I'm writing this code for class, and I keep getting a segmentation fault(core dumped) error. Why is this happening?

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
char *store[100];int freq[100]={0};int flag;int count=0;int t;
for(int i=0,j=0;i<argc;i++)
{
    for(int z=0;z<count;z++)
    {
        if(*argv[i]==*store[z]) flag=1;t=z;break;
    }
       if(flag==0) {*store[j]=*argv[i];j++; count++;}
       else freq[t]+=1;
       flag=0;
}
for(int x=0;x<count;x++) cout<<*store[x]<<"\t"<<freq[x]<<endl;
```

}

Comment: Your `store` is an array of 100 pointers, but they don't point anywhere. You have to assign them some values before you can use them. Or maybe they should be just `char` and not pointers?

Comment: I tried with char, but got a error saying can't compare char and *char

Comment: @Yolo Of course, because you cannot compare a string with a single character. You have to iterate through all chars in a string.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing an unitialised variable, causing undefined behaviour.(int flag)

In the first iteration count will be equal to 0, so the inner loop will not happen, hence no assignment to flag, before using.

Comment: Is there a way to initialize every element to same value?

Comment: The access of the uninitialzed `int flag` would not cause a segfault.

Comment: @MartinZabel The Standard says that the use of a local uninitialized variable is undefined behavior. From that point on, we can't deterministically say what the program will do, but you're definitely correct it saying this wasn't the only problem with the code. This is because compilers are free to make optimizations, and these to be effective assume you're code is sane, and doesn't use uninitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want compare *argv[1] with *store[z], but what is the value of *store[z] ?

before using any variable, initialize it !  if it is a pointer, make sure that memory is malloced for it.

Answer (score 0):

`char *argv[]` and `char *store[100]` are array of pointers to `char`, i.e. typically an array of null-terminated strings.

The array `store` is not initialized, so that, it holds 100 pointers pointing to some undefined memory location.

In line:

```
if(*argv[i]==*store[z]) flag=1;t=z;break;
```

you are dereferencing the pointer at index `z` of array `store`. As this pointer is undefined, the program typically tries to access a protected memory location. Thus, it segfaults.